# Display mysql blob field as image/file in vue.js using axios and express.js

Tags: mysql, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

i’m using **express.js** to store images and pdf files into a **Mysql** database .
now i’m looking for displaying images in vueJs code (i'm using **nuxt.js**)  by the img tag and also pdf files , I’m really stuck I’ve tried everything but nothing works…
my table files :

`id : autoincrement`
 `type: string`
 `name: string`
 `ddata: blob`

my controller :

```js
                module.exports.liste = function (req, res, next) {
                    con.query("SELECT * FROM files", function (err, results, fields) {
                   if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            message: 'Error getting records.',
                            err: er`
                        });
                    }

           if (results.length > 0) {
                return res.json(results);
            } else {
                return res.json([]);
            }
        });
   }
```

i get data like this :

```js
async asyncData(context){
    const {data} = await context.$axios.get('/api/files')
    return {
      files : data
    }
 },
```

hmtl vue:

```html
<v-list-item v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">
            {{ file.id }}....  {{ file.type }} .... {{ file.name }}....
             <img :src="file.ddata" />
  </v-list-item>
```

Thank you in advance for your reply